# Installing python-qpid-proton fails on MacOSX python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, qpid

This previously hasn't happened so I don't know what has changed over the course of the last few months but unfortunately I've found myself in the position of having to re-install python-qpid-proton and now I'm running into errors that I can not find a good fix for at all.

### The Problem

If I run the following line:

```sh
pip install python-qpid-proton
```

I get the following output all in red:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/src/core/log.c:20:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/src/core/log_private.h:27:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/log.h:23:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/logger.h:32:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/object.h:26:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/types.h:27:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/type_compat.h:75:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:79:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
    typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
            ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/src/core/log.c:20:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/src/core/log_private.h:27:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/log.h:23:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/logger.h:32:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/object.h:26:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/types.h:27:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/type_compat.h:75:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:81:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/endian.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/src/core/log.c:20:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/src/core/log_private.h:27:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/log.h:23:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/logger.h:32:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/object.h:26:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/types.h:27:
    In file included from /private/var/folders/l_/y17fz4qs6mn4wvdb781hnn50dbr4xv/T/pip-install-01kp069a/python-qpid-proton/include/proton/type_compat.h:75:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:95:9: error: unknown type name 'u_int64_t'
    typedef u_int64_t               u_quad_t;       /* quads */
            ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'xcrun' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm not sure what I should do at this point or if I should go to the creators and report this.  Any help would be appreciated.

### Environment - Edit

I use Python 3.7 and now 3.8.  I've installed this using homebrew.  *I do not use the OSX version which is python 2.7.* I also use `virtualenv` to create as an environment for python applications.  The reason why I had to reinstall qpid is because if I let my solution sit for a while (working on something else) then I come back to it it breaks.  I think the reason is that I inadvertently updated python from 3.7 to 3.8 using `brew update`.  Which I probably shouldn't have done.  This broke virtualenv using python3.7.

So as you know, I use a virtual environment for my application.  I'm using 3.8 python and when I'm in my virtual environment and running `pip install` the above problem happens.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well!  Qpid Proton doesn't work with 3.8 it looks like.  3.7.8 installs Qpid Proton just fine.

As a solution I had to bypass homebrew and use pyenv.

Using pyenv's directory and virtualenv, I was able to successfully re-install qpid and run the app.  I still have to go back and clean up homebrew and get rid of python entirely on that ecosphere so I can control it using pyenv instead.  Essentially when brew updated to 3.8 (without me knowing it) it broke my code.  Going back and downgrading through homebrew seemed expensive so I opted to use another python environment tool.

So anyone out there, don't upgrade to 3.8 yet if you're using Qpid Proton from Apache.

Answer (score 1):

What python and environment are you using?  ...if you don't know, you're likely just using the standard/default python on OSX.

You probably a) don't want to be using that and b) don't want to be trying to install new modules into it as it's used by the OS, installed into the system space, isn't the most recent python version and it's hard to use as a user for user projects.

If you're not already, you should try using a python distribution/package manager.  I use Conda personally.

Likely if you use that, you wont run into the types of issues you're seeing here.

Comment: Hi Richard.  I have updated my question to provide missing information you require in your answer.

Comment: Hi Paul - I personally gave up trying to use homebrew to install/use python for similiar problems, and switched to Anaconda, where I didn't run into any problems like you're seeing.  I'm not sure at all, but the problem you're getting looks like it's trying to install a wheel (compiled module), and getting problems due to the compiled version not working with your version of XCode/OS.  I personally can't offer any help, except as I said - I had similiar problems trying to use homebrew, and fixed them by moving to anaconda. ...sorry I can't be any more help than that!

Comment: What's weird is that 3.7 works.  This may be a real issue with qpid now that I'm letting this marinate for a while, while I work on some other tasks that need to get done.  I'm going to first try and downgrade python back to 3.7 and see if I can compile the plugin that way.  I'm going to look into Anaconda in the meantime though, thanks for that tip.